# How can I find and/or print sudo's lecture file?

Tags: sudo

I'm using Ubuntu and I would like to find and/or print the sudo lecture that is printed to the screen the first time a user executes a sudo command. How can I do this? I'm unable to find the lecture file.

Comment: You could use `apt-get source sudo` to install the source package and then search for the lecture in the source code (`cd sudo; grep -A4 "usual lecture"`).

Answer (score 12):

See `man sudoers`

> *lecture_file*
> Path to a file containing an alternate sudo lecture that will be used in place of the standard lecture if the named file exists.  By default, **sudo uses a built-in lecture**.

So, if you wish to change the text, add it to a file and point to it from `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults        lecture_file = /etc/sudoers.lecture
```

According to the [change log for Ubuntu Qantal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/sudo/+changelog), `sudo` is now compiled `--without-lecture`.

The default text, when compiled in, is:

> #define DEFAULT_LECTURE "\n" \
>     "We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System\n" \
>     "Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:\n\n" \
>     "    #1) Respect the privacy of others.\n" \
>     "    #2) Think before you type.\n" \
>     "    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.\n\n"

Comment: Yes, I read the man page, but I still dont understand. If I try: nano /etc/sudoers.lecture there is no file present. How do I print or open the default lecture file?

Comment: @turtle The default lecture is part of the source code, it's not in a plaintext file. You may be able to use `strings`, or similar, to extract it.

Comment: Yes, in theory, this is exactly what I'm looking for; however, I do not get this output on Ubuntu or OS X.

Comment: @turtle I have no idea about OSX, but on Ubuntu it is not compiled in.

Answer (score 1):

The lecture text is compiled into the sudo binary.  Issuing the following `strings` command will output the default lecture text.

```
strings /usr/bin/sudo | grep -A4 "usual lecture"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is starting to make some sense. However, on Ubuntu, the command you provided does not output anything.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?  I am using 10.04 LTS to test.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin).

Comment: Does `strings /usr/bin/sudo | grep "lecture"` output anything?

Comment: It shows a bunch of text. Here's a sample: `--prefix=/usr -v --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-`